# Change background of Expandable List child view when an element in child layout is clicked

Tags: android, background, expandablelistview, pressed

I need to change the background of the child view in Expandable list view when child is clicked.

Child row layout is something like:

```
<RelativeLayout>     //Selector is placed for this layout
    ....
   <RelativeLayout>
      .... 
       <RelativeLayout>
         ....
         <TextView>
        ....
    ....
```

selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable= "@drawable/greyish"/>
</selector>
```

Now, when i clicked on TextView i want to change the background of whole row ( top most Relative layout comprise on every view with in child layout). How can i trigger the selector of top level relative layout.

Also, when OnChildClick() receives callback then row's background changes( because of selector placed in top level layout).

My attempt is:

In TextView's onlclick method:

```
   ((RelativeLayout)(nameView.getParent().getParent().getParent())).setPressed(true);
```

but this is not resulting in row layout to change background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

ultimately you want to trigger the selector of parentView from its childView.

**Solution**

In your parent layout,add this line:

```
android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
```

and if you have the reference of parentView in your java code then you can achieve the task by using:

```
parentView.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
```

where,parentView is your parent layout i.e.:`RelativeLayout`

**Note:**

make sure that your childview is not duplicating parent's state.
i.e.: `android:duplicateParentState` or `childView.setDuplicateParentState(true)`

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: can you show the code? you are supposed to add it after you get reference of `parentView`.not when you handle `onClick` event of child.

Comment: Inside onclick of textView     ((RelativeLayout)(nameView.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.child_row_wrapper))).setAddStatesFromChildren(true);

Comment: @GauravGupta: you should `not` do it there.you should write it when you `inflate` your custom layout.

Comment: your suggestion worked for me, i was making some mistakes that day, we have to pass the event state level by level. Hence this attribute need to added to every parent layout of textview utill we reach the top most relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just give an id to the layout where you want the elements to be colored and then something like:

```
layout_with_child_views = (RelativeLayout)nameView.getRootView().findViewById(id)
```

If your method returns the correct view then you could of course also stick to that.

Then fetch all child elements and change the background color:

```
for (int i = 0; i < layout_with_child_views.getChildCount(); i++) {
   View child = (View) layout_with_child_views 
                .getChildAt(i);
   tintBackground(child);       
}

private void tintBackground(View view) {
    ColorDrawable[] color = { new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE),
            new ColorDrawable(Color.GREY) };
    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
    trans.startTransition(500);

}
```

**Edit:** I have been searching abit and to me it seems like you should be able to use the available listeners of ExpandableListView, so that in your ExpandableListAdapter:

```
    @Override
    public void onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // use the parent to set default color to all other entries

        // v is the view within the expandable list/ListView that was clicked
               for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
                   View child = (View) v.getChildAt(i);
                   // do highlighting       
               }
    }
```

I have not tried this myself and am currently unable to setup a test project. Just wanted to give you an alternative approach in case you have not tried something similar.

Comment: I tried `setBackGroundColor()`on `layout_with_child_views` but this did not changed the background color. As you suggested, now i will try `setBackgroundDrawable()` too and let you know, but this will set a `permanent color`, whereas i want just `highlight on onclick()` `

Comment: Ok was worth a try. To your first comment: this was meant to be run in onClick. Then of course you would have to see if the onClick happens inside an already highlighted row or not and make sure to recolor other rows if the click happens in a new expandable list.

Comment: But  `setBackgroundDrawable()`/`setBackGroundColor()` doesnot result in highlighting the layout

Comment: Does their exist childSelector for Expandable list that would be similar to listSelector in ListView.

Comment: I don't want to highlight Group view on child view click. What i need is: `highlight child view when an element in the child view is click`

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood that. Modified the answer/suggestion

Comment: I won't be receiving callback on onChildClick() because click event is already consumed my textview's on click. Your approach can work if their when i can trigger onChildClick() from onClick(). Can i set something like setChildClicked(boolean).

Comment: I would try and remove the onClick from the TextView, as the code is suppose to do the highlighting as your onClick via XML tries to achieve.

Comment: But i have perform some business logic on the click of text view. Click on empty space does something else and click on text view does something else. but highlighting the row is common for both click events

Comment: in the onChildClick() you should be able to locate each seperate views with v.findViewById(id) and add the logic you want to them.